# How exactly does motion produce thermal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinematics, temperature

How exactly does motion produce heat?
An electron that is moving from a higher energy state to a lower energy state can dissipate this energy as heat. Conversely, if the atom is provided with heat, the electron can absorb energy and move to a higher energy level.

On the other hand, thermal energy is described as the motion of particles.
How exactly do these two examples describe what "heat" is? It seams to me that qualitatively they don't provide the same definition

What exactly is "heat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the perspective of Statistical Physics, particles interact exchanging energy in the process (e.g. an inelastic collision or an atom absorbing a photon). The heat would be a macroscopic variable that encodes the sum of all of these microscopic exchanges.

In other words, the heat is a macroscopic flux of energy that can have many different microscopic processes involved. Its precise relationship with the microscopic dynamics depends on the specific system.

Comment: *In other words, the heat is a macroscopic flux of energy* A block of say iron is kept at constant temperature (perfectly insulated). It contains heat energy. But where the 'macroscopic flux of energy'?

Comment: How do you explain your hands heating up when you rub them together? Joule's experiment?

Comment: @Gert First question: In my nomenclature, the block of Iron would have some **Thermal Energy** or simply **Energy**. Indeed, the system you mention has an energy that can be understood as the sum of the energies of the particles. The equilibrium implies that there is no net transport of energy (macroscopically), hence no heat. I would understand **Heat Energy** as the energy that could be extracted as heat if the equilibrium condition is broken (e.g. if the Iron block is in contact with a different system at a lower temperature). Anyway, I ignore the definition of Heat Energy (Hamiltionan?).

Comment: @Gert Second question: Microscopically, the particles of one hand collide with particles of the other, resulting in energy exchange. There are more collisions in the contact surface of the hands than in the rest of the hand, resulting in a non-zero macroscopic net transport that we call Heat.

Comment: You're talking about *heat* **transfer**.

Comment: @Gert In Statistical Physics and Thermodynamics, and as far as I know, "heat" is always associated with heat transfer. From [Wikipedia][1]: "*In thermodynamics, heat is energy in transfer to or from a thermodynamic system ...*". However, I ignore if Heat has a different meaning in other contexts.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat#

Answer (score 1):

> How exactly does motion produce heat?

Motion does not necessarily "produce" heat. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference.

> An electron that is moving from a higher energy state to a lower
> energy state can dissipate this energy as heat.

An electron that is moving from a higher energy state to a lower energy state is doing so by radiating photons (electromagnetic energy). That energy can transfer to another object in the form of heat if the temperature of the other object is less than the object radiating the energy.

> Conversely, if the atom is provided with heat, the electron can absorb
> energy and move to a higher energy level.

Yes, but for the atom of an object to absorb energy in the form of heat, some other object at higher temperature must emit that energy.

> On the other hand, thermal energy is described as the motion of
> particles.

The term "thermal energy" should be avoided. It is the internal (microscopic) kinetic energy at the atomic/molecular level that is due to the motion of the particles.

> How exactly do these two examples describe what "heat" is? It seams to
> me that qualitatively they don't provide the same definition

The two examples describe the absorption or emission of electromagnetic energy in the form of heat only if that absorption or emission is due to a temperature difference between the objects emitting and absorbing the energy.

> What exactly is "heat"?

Heat is energy transfer between objects due solely to temperature difference. Period. The mechanisms of that transfer are conduction, convection, and radiation. The examples you described are generally (but not necessarily) due to heat transfer by radiation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not understand your point. What is "thermal energy" and why should it be avoided?

Comment: The term is vague. Some use it as a synonym for heat. Others as a synonym for internal kinetic energy. Noted author of Heat and Thermodynamic Mark Zemansky suggests the term be avoided

Comment: And what's the difference between heat and heat transfer?

Comment: Grammatically, one should just say heat since the word transfer would be redundant as it is already in the definition of heat. Grammatically that  makes heat transfer “energy transfer transfer”. But many folks (including me occasionally) say heat transfer. In my opinion it’s just sloppy English

Comment: I would only add that it’s only my opinion